# Javascript regex with optional groups matches the empty string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to take a string that looks something like

```
"[go]$$Bcm11 Prisoners:"
```

and match the `Bcm11` portion.  Every single portion of it is optional (except technically, if the m appears, the , so I'm using the regex:

```
/([bBWw])?(c?)m?([0-9]*)/
```

Unfortunately, this cheerfully matches the empty string. Removing a '?' or '*' gets the right behavior, but makes that component non-optional.

Is there any way to force this regex to match a non-empty string when it's available?

Comment: please give more examples of what should and should not match... right now I'm not sure what you mean by the question

Comment: Yeah, I should have been clearer. The $$ will definitely be there, so I can probably use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a lookahead `(?=...)` to make sure there's something in the string.
This makes sure that at least one of your allowable characters is present.

```
/(?=[BbWwcm0-9])([bBWw])?(c?)m?([0-9]*)/
```

The performance would be much improved, however, if you could add a `^`, `$`, or even `\b` to your regex. For example,

```
/\b(?=[BbWwcm0-9])([bBWw])?(c?)m?([0-9]*)\b/
```

which makes sure your match at least grabs the entire word and not just (say) the `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure tell it to look for the string inside of the $$ and the space using [lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Thanks. I think that gives me enough to go on.

Comment: Seems that javascript doesn't support lookbehind, unless what I'm reading is out of date.

Comment: Right, Javascript doesn't have support for lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment `$$` will always be there. If that's the case then you can simply use:

```
/\$\$([bBWw]?c?m?\d*)/
```